# SSH Key management for a CD server using a private GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am setting up a Continuous Deployment (CD) server which periodically pulls master branch from my private git repository, hosted on GitHub. At first I used my own SSH key to clone and pull the code on the server, but I am feeling somewhat uneasy about leaving my private key on this CD (I use it for many other servers). I would rather keep my private key on my laptop only. Currently I am using a new SSH key I generated exclusively for purpose of this deployment. But I still had to add it to my GitHub keys, so it grants the full rights to all the other repos that it does not need to have access to. While it is an improvement (as this key cannot be used to access some other servers my normal key grants access to) it still allows way more access than it needs to.

Is there a better, more secure way to manage authentication to a git server (GitHub more specifically)? Is there any established practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On github.com, your can go to the repository page, choose *Settings* -> *Deploy keys*.
Generate a specific key pair for this purpose on your machine:

```
ssh-keygen -f my_private_repo
```

Upload the contents of `my_private_repo.pub` as new deploy key, don't tick the *write access* checkbox.
Now you can use the private key when checking our the repository in your CD system. In `bamboo` you can add a repository of type 'Git' select authentication type 'SSH private key' and choose to 'Use custom SSH key'.
I don't know if this would also work on, e.g., Travis.

Comment: The issue with deploy keys is that a deploy key can only access a *single* repo. How do you do when you have a server that needs to access several repos?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the option to add a deployment SSH key with read only access to given repo alone is the Settings tab of a repository on github.